# windows 7 performance- outlook start up takes long time after a reboot

Tags: windows

We just received a new machine and we put Windows 7 x64 enterprise on it.

However the end user moaned that it is slower than his old one (2 yrs old, Windows 7 Pro, x64).

Both machines come from Dell and the new machine definately has slightly better spec.

I wrote a couple of powershell script to do the following and log the time elapsed:

(1) launch outlook2010

(2) a long "for" loop

(3) file upload to a server network share.

The results show that the 2 machines perform similarly on task (2) and (3), however task (1) sees some strange result:

On the old machine, the time spent to start outlook.exe is always about 280ms. On the new machine, however, the 1st launch after a reboot is always much longer, from 2 ~ 10 sec. But once you have started outlook once (before another reboot), the following start up is much quicker, 10ms or so.

So how can outlook start up takes a near constant period of time on one machine, but very differently on another? Any ideas?

Comment: What OS did the old machine have out of curiosity?

Comment: @NathanC Good question. The old one is Windows 7 Pro, x64.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a plugin. Try disabling them one-by-one and see if the initial startup time improves.